# Name of an old show where hero embarks on a quest to free his kingdom from evil

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember this.
the main hero on his quest to free the kingdom from the evil that took over found a teenage girl who had grown up in the forest and can't remember her parents and reluctant to trust people until he convinced her to join with his buddy. (she has a pet) (she wears a green skirt i think)
then they went on the adventure to save the kingdom VSing monsters and minions.
they stop in a village at one point to help it out.
thanks for any help

Comment: This maaaaay be the plot of about 99.99999% of all fantasy stories.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like *The Adventures of Sinbad* (original release: September 28, 1996 – May 24, 1998):

> In the first few episodes: After two years at sea, Sinbad returns to
>   his home, Baghdad. The city is very different from the Baghdad he
>   remembers. It is now in the control of a prince and the grand vizier.
>   He lands himself in prison, where he is reacquainted with his elder
>   brother, Doubar, and discovers he is to be beheaded. When the princess
>   is kidnapped, the Caliph of Baghdad says Sinbad is the only man he
>   knows who is capable of facing Turok, the man who captured the
>   princess. Before Sinbad is beheaded, Doubar comes to the rescue and
>   sets him free. The brothers meet up with the rest of Sinbad's crew and
>   proceed to Turok's lair, in search for Princess Adena. Sinbad tells his crew they need the help of his and Doubar's old mentor, Master Dim-Dim, so the crew head off for the Isle of Dawn, where he resides. They arrive at the island where they meet Dim-Dim and his new
>   apprentice, Maeve, along with her avian companion, Dermott, a hawk.
>   After the crew leaves the island, Dim-Dim is taken into magical limbo
>   by an enemy. Many episodes in the two seasons mention Dim-Dim, however
>   with the show being cancelled without making the third season, there
>   is never any resolution for finding him. After Dim-Dim goes missing,
>   Maeve decides to join Sinbad and his crew in their search for the lost
>   Master. They find many adventures along the way. Sinbad and his crews
>   goodness of heart always shines through in each episode.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia's article on *The Adventures of Sinbad*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Sinbad)